# CubeSat: When designing the PID Controller of the CubeSat, what are some constraints that you need to take into account?

Tags: pid, flight-controller

For a 1U CubeSat project in which we need to design the controller for it.

We decided to not include any propulsion system to keep it light, we'll just essentially drop the satellite on LEO and let it naturally decay over time.

The controller will control the attitude, our team thinks that a PID controller would work for this. The actuators are Reaction Wheels and Magnetorques. The IMU consists of a Gyroscope, Magnetometer and an Accelerometer.

Let's say that all the Control System has been modeled (all the state space equations had been derived). And we need now to design a PID controller (we'll leverage the automatic tuning Simulink tool to get the optimal PID gains) for this system.

My question is the following:

What are the contraints that I need to consider when desinging my PID controller, i.e when getting the PID gains, and once I know all these contrants how to implement them into my PID controller using the automatic tuning feature in Simulink?

I hope it makes sense. Thanks a lot!